# DataGrid, Star, Auto, layout

Tags: c#, wpf

I have DataGrids that are getting resized when certain Grids are collapsed.  In the default scenario, I'd like to have two rows in a column be like this:

```
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.65*"/>            
            <RowDefinition Height="0.35*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

When I resize in the code behind, I seem to only have the option for the height/widths to be of type:

```
.RowDefinitions[i].Height = GridLength.Auto;
.ColumnDefinitions[i].Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
```

Is there a way I can revert back to my original .65* and .35*?  Thanks.

Comment: By the way the star refers to a ratio - and the total ratio does not need to add up to 1. Since you are basically saying that the first row should be twice as high as the second row, you could just as easily use 2star and 1star.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.65*` can be written as `new GridLength(.65, GridUnitType.Star);`

The first parameter in the `GridLength` constructor is the number in front of the `*`, and `Height="*"` is really `Height="1*"`

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the following?

```
.RowDefinitions[0].Height = new GridLength(0.65, GridUnitType.Star);
.RowDefinitions[1].Height = new GridLength(0.35, GridUnitType.Star);
```

This should be equivalent to:

```
<RowDefinition Height="0.65*"/>            
<RowDefinition Height="0.35*"/>
```